# CSV file wont upload?

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

I got this data scrape, an when i run profile i get this error Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type" i have saved it as UTF-8 without BOM. I've never attempted to upload products via a csv so i don't really know what i should be looking for.

I have attached an image of my spreadshseet columns it would be helpful if you can see whether it looks correct or even if you could attach me one so i can see the difference.

[image: csv here]

Comment: dont you want to try magmi....

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your image and the error it would seem you don't have a column for type. According the the [magento docs](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/data-csv-files.html) it would appear that a column type needs tonne present